# what will happen if I pass a not pointer type to store instruction?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

When using the `store` instruction in LLVM IR code, I found this in the document:

> There are two arguments to the store instruction: a value to store and
>   an address at which to store it. The type of the  operand
>   must be a pointer to the first class type of the  operand.

But the truth is that if I pass a llvm value which type is not a pointer to the function`builder.CreateStore(constInt0, v1);` (v1 is a 32bits integer type, not a pointer type), the builder didn't assert error, but generate the IR code:

`store i32 0, i32 %1`

while normally code for storage is more like:

`store i32 0, i32* %1`

But if I pass a not pointer type value to `builder.CreateLoad(v1);`, the builder will assert an error:

```
typename cast_retty<X, Y *>::ret_type llvm::cast(Y *) [X = llvm::PointerType, Y = llvm::Type]: Assertion `isa<X>(Val) && "cast<Ty>() argument of incompatible type!"' failed.
```

So why builder allowed me to pass a non-pointer value? And what will happen if the `store i32 0, i32 %1` runs?

Comment: It'll break at some point during the compile, either during [verification](https://llvm.org/doxygen/namespacellvm.html#af8c14262d42a312c9026452162c9e0a6) or during code generation. LLVM often issues error messages early, very soon after you made the mistake, but sometimes LLVM notices the problem much later than it potentially could have.

Comment: Have you tried running it? I would expect that you can't run it because the bitcode fails to validate. Certainly `llvm-as` or `clang` will refuse to compile something like `store i32 0, i32 %1`. I am surprised that you don't get an assertion error. Are you running a debug build with assertions enabled?

Comment: I tested with verification function and lli. Verification function did not notice this error while lli report the type error. I'm still curious the purpose why IRBuilder can generate a non-pointer operand to a store instruction.